# Crawled property question

Tags: search

I have a custom list with following list columns: Description and Text. Column type is multiply lines of text.
I see both of them in Crawled properties: ows_Description and ows_Text. I created Managed properties (Description and Text) and mapped them to crawled properties.
 When I search for something in Description, I got some results back but not when I search for Text.
There is no versioning or content approval in the list. I see no difference in setup. Both columns and Managed properties were created the same time.
Why one of the columns is searchable but other not?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you try to index a simple string like "**Hello World**".

Read this article can help: [index search column](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/07/what-makes-sharepoint-column-searchable.html)

If you are indexing Nordic languages this characters (æ, ø, æ) could make your test hit some kind of software deficiencies in the code.

Little Troubleshooting:

1) I would recommend avoid those names for the MP, in order to no confuse them with the defaults ones, but if it is mandatory them check:
The MP are Searchable,Queryable and Retrievable.
The order of the mapped crawled properties show the selected CP on top. or select include content from all CP

2) If it still not working,  you need to troubleshoot the crawl and see what is indexed in every property, them use Powershell to increase the log level to verboseEx.

```
# Increase Loglevel
Get-sploglevel | where {$_.Area -like “*Server Search*”} | Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx
#Reset loglevel
Clear-SPLogLevel | where {$_.Area -like “*Server Search*”}
```

with the verboseEX enabled executed a full crawl and monitor the log; filtering by EventID af7zf.
That should show you whether something is indexed in ows_Text.